# How to uninstall all .NET Framework 4.6.1 Language and Targeting Packs at once?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, language, .net-framework, language-pack

Somehow, I've managed to install countless language and targeting packs for the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1. I assume it happened while installing Visual Studio 2015.1. Usually I take extra care not to install *any* language packs, but this one somehow slipped through the cracks. The result is this:

[image: 4.6 Targeting packs]

And the list goes on. I've uninstalled a couple of then already by individually selecting them and uninstalling. However, this is a time consuming process.
So, can I uninstall these packs *at once*?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this .NET Framework Cleanup Tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx